# Is it feasible to use Guava Cache as a "helper" for my own persistent cache?

Tags: java, guava

I'm looking to relieve the pressure on a "lookup service" that hits a database each time, by putting a caching layer between the service provider and the service client.  I want this caching layer to be persistent and to fit more objects than RAM would allow, so a vanilla Guava Cache won't do.  I've looked into things like EhCache and CouchBase but have decided to roll my own for various reasons.

It's pretty easy to write the naive code for this persistent caching layer.  However, I know enough about caching to realize that there are a lot of concurrency issues to handle, and I am pretty sure I won't get all of them right the first time.  For example there is the "thundering herd" problem, where a cache miss could cause a lot of simultaneous requests to the backing service for the exact same object. It struck me that this is exactly the type of thing that a LoadingCache already handles.  Does it seem like a reasonable idea to try to get Guava to do the hard stuff dealing with concurrency, and just plug in my own subclass(es) to do the actual object retrieval and storage?  I'm not sure where the exact boundaries would be in terms of what I would subclass or override, but I can figure that out if this isn't just a totally misguided idea.  I haven't seen examples of extending / customizing Guava caching, so if there are any examples and or documents to look at, I'd be interested in those.

Comment: I am really wondering what would motivate one to spend the time to implement his/her own cache over using an existing one, there are so many prod-proven solutions out there.

Comment: "I'm not sure where the exact boundaries would be in terms of what I would subclass or override":  The boundaries are that you can't subclass anything except the basic `CacheLoader`.

Comment: @vtheron I concede your point in general, and probably in this specific case too.  However, none of the solutions I looked at were a perfect fit, so I started exploring other avenues.  In addition: coding is fun; installing and configuring an all-singing, all-dancing product that sort of solves my problem is not :)

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I get your drift, that sounds like it puts my idea into the "totally misguided" category, if not on merit then on practicality.  I recognize your name from the Guava wiki, so I am going to take it as authoritative.

Comment: @jfrank "coding is fun; installing and configuring an all-singing, all-dancing product that sort of solves my problem is not" I yield :)

Comment: You can easily implement a cache at the top of Couchbase. This will give you the capacity to "cache" more data than you RAM and in fact use Memcached behind the scene to cache the data (instead the VM) - Some equivalent work has been done around SpringCache+Couchbase https://github.com/couchbaselabs/spring-data-couchbase

Comment: @TugGrall That sounds intriguing.  I was hoping for something that could separate out the concurrency part of caching from the persistence part, so I could store the data however I wanted, but your link is a better fit than anything else I've found so far.

Comment: Yes, I've actually done this exact thing. Mostly because I really liked the interface for the Guava Caches. I wish I could show you them but they are for a client. I intend to redo them on github someday. Note that you will probably also need to build your own CacheBuilder as well

Comment: @ryber If you can share a high-level overview of what you did, that would be helpful.  I don't know if there's a way for you to contact me directly through my Stack Overflow profile, if you don't want to post anything here.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was very simple.  I make a normal LoadingCache, and perform some extra operations in the load and reload methods.  This gave me the hooks (i.e. the load and reload methods of CacheLoader) to look in my local database for an object, and call the remote service if I don't find it and persist it, without worrying that many threads would be trying to get the same object, due to all the concurrency guards that Guava provides.

I'm sure it's far from how the cache is intended to be used, since I'm actually setting the maximumSize on my cache to 0, so that my load function is always called.  (For a variety of reasons I want to serve the objects from persistent storage each time, not from RAM).  I haven't tested it thoroughly but it seems to be behaving as I want.  The overall effect is a pull-through "object mirror", acting as a self-updating copy of the upstream service.